# The meaning of "constrainOnly" in \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

The image help can resize the image, but I don't understand the `constrainOnly` parameter in it. What is the function of `->constrainOnly(true)` and `->constrainOnly(false)`?

### code example

```
return $this->_imageHelper
        ->init($product,'category_page_list')
        ->constrainOnly(FALSE)
        ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
        ->keepFrame(FALSE)
        ->resize(240, 300)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
->constrainOnly(true)
```

This will **not** resize an image that is smaller than the dimensions inside the resize() part. **Default value** is true in Magento 2.1.

```
->constrainOnly(false)
```

This will resize an image that is smaller than the dimensions inside the resize() part.